# How to fix issues installing 'fields' package to work with 'rworldmap'

Tags: r, field, rworldmap

I'm attempting to use the rworldmap package and for some reason it is not able to install the dependent 'fields' package. I've tried the normal 'install.packages()' command, I've tried using the GUI (with install dependencies checked), installing from source, and installing from GitHub and none works. I tried to just install the fields package separately, and it always fails. Both appear to install and I get the message that it has been downloaded to the library. I can see rworldmap appear in the directory but the fields package does not.

I'm using R 3.3.

If there is no fix for this, does anyone have other suggestions for how to easily plot a global heatmap using country codes?

Comment: What is the error message you get when running `install.packages('fields')`?

Comment: ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fields’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/fields’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fields’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/private/var/folders/ft/155f7gmj63g2yd0c38jzxbp40000gn/T/RtmpY1NJQQ/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Some have noted there could be an issue with something called fortran 4.8. But I don't know what this is, nor how to install for R to test.

Comment: Try manually deleting the `rworldmap` and `fields` directories from your `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/` folder, then install `fields`, then install `rworldmap`.

Comment: Okay, tried that. Now I get a different error: Loading required package: sp
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘dotCall64’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rworldmap’

Comment: An error reporting "compilation failed" suggests you a) are trying to install a package from source, and b) don't have all the needed resources installed. (This is obviously on a Mac, but you need to specify which if any of the development tools  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/  you have for your unstated version of OSX.) You might also explain why you are not installing from binary versions of packages.